# Trouble installing Communications package in Octave 4.2

Tags: matlab, signals, octave

I have a problem installing Communications package for Octave on Ubuntu 18 I started with installing liboctave

```
sudo apt-get install liboctave-dev
```

then I installed depency packages for communications package:

```
pkg install control-3.1.0.tar.gz

pkg install signal-1.4.0.tar.gz

pkg install communications-1.2.1.tar.gz
```

when I arrived at the third command it gave me this error which is probably due to use of deprecated code:

```
    cyclpoly.cc: In function ‘Array<int> filter_gf2(const Array<int>&, const Array<int>&, const Array<int>&,const int&)’: cyclpoly.cc:41:25: warning: ‘octave_idx_type Array<T>::length() const [with T = int; octave_idx_type = int]’ is deprecated: use 'numel' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]    int x_len = x.length ();
                         ^ In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Sparse.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/oct.h:30,
                 from cyclpoly.cc:24: /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Array.h:354:19: note: declared here    octave_idx_type length (void) const { return numel (); }
                   ^~~~~~ cyclpoly.cc: In function ‘octave_value_list Fcyclpoly(const octave_value_list&, int)’: cyclpoly.cc:220:55: warning: ‘octave_idx_type Array<T>::length() const [with T = double; octave_idx_type= int]’ is deprecated: use 'numel' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
             cyclic_polys.resize (cyclic_polys.length ()+1);
                                                       ^ In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Sparse.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/oct.h:30,
                 from cyclpoly.cc:24: /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Array.h:354:19: note: declared here    octave_idx_type length (void) const { return numel (); }
                   ^~~~~~ cyclpoly.cc:221:47: warning: ‘octave_idx_type Array<T>::length() const [with T = double; octave_idx_type= int]’ is deprecated: use 'numel' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
             cyclic_polys(cyclic_polys.length ()-1) = (double)i;
                                               ^ In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Sparse.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/oct.h:30,
                 from cyclpoly.cc:24: /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Array.h:354:19: note: declared here    octave_idx_type length (void) const { return numel (); }
                   ^~~~~~ cyclpoly.cc:236:61: warning: ‘octave_idx_type Array<T>::length() const [with T = double; octave_idx_type= int]’ is deprecated: use 'numel' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                   cyclic_polys.resize (cyclic_polys.length ()+1);
                                                             ^ In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Sparse.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/oct.h:30,
                 from cyclpoly.cc:24: /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Array.h:354:19: note: declared here    octave_idx_type length (void) const { return numel (); }
                   ^~~~~~ cyclpoly.cc:237:53: warning: ‘octave_idx_type Array<T>::length() const [with T = double; octave_idx_type= int]’ is deprecated: use 'numel' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                   cyclic_polys(cyclic_polys.length ()-1) = (double)i;
                                                     ^ In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Sparse.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/oct.h:30,
                 from cyclpoly.cc:24: /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Array.h:354:19: note: declared here    octave_idx_type length (void) const { return numel (); }
                   ^~~~~~ cyclpoly.cc:247:28: warning: ‘octave_idx_type Array<T>::length() const [with T = double; octave_idx_type= int]’ is deprecated: use 'numel' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]    if (cyclic_polys.length () == 0)
                            ^ In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Sparse.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/oct.h:30,
                 from cyclpoly.cc:24: /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Array.h:354:19: note: declared here    octave_idx_type length (void) const { return numel (); }
                   ^~~~~~ cyclpoly.cc:257:46: warning: ‘octave_idx_type Array<T>::length() const [with T = double; octave_idx_type= int]’ is deprecated: use 'numel' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
           Matrix polys (cyclic_polys.length (), m+1, 0);
                                              ^ In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Sparse.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/oct.h:30,
                 from cyclpoly.cc:24: /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Array.h:354:19: note: declared here    octave_idx_type length (void) const { return numel (); }
                   ^~~~~~ cyclpoly.cc:258:53: warning: ‘octave_idx_type Array<T>::length() const [with T = double; octave_idx_type= int]’ is deprecated: use 'numel' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
           for (int i = 0 ; i < cyclic_polys.length (); i++)
                                                     ^ In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Sparse.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/oct.h:30,
                 from cyclpoly.cc:24: /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Array.h:354:19: note: declared here    octave_idx_type length (void) const { return numel (); }
                   ^~~~~~ cyclgen.cc: In function ‘Array<int> filter_gf2(const Array<int>&, const Array<int>&, const Array<int>&, const int&)’: cyclgen.cc:32:25: warning: ‘octave_idx_type Array<T>::length() const [with T = int; octave_idx_type = int]’ is deprecated: use 'numel' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]    int x_len = x.length ();
                         ^ In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Sparse.h:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/MSparse.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/MatrixType.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/mx-base.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Matrix.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/oct.h:30,
                 from cyclgen.cc:23: /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/Array.h:354:19: note: declared here    octave_idx_type length (void) const { return numel (); }
                   ^~~~~~ In file included from galois.h:24:0,
                 from galois-def.cc:21: /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/config.h:28:2: warning:
#warning "config.h has been deprecated; there is no need to include it directly" [-Wcpp]  #warning "config.h has been deprecated; there is no need to include it directly"   ^~~~~~~ In file included from galois-def.cc:21:0: galois.h:25:10: fatal error: octave/base-lu.h: No such file or directory  #include <octave/base-lu.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. make: *** [galois-def.o] Error 1 make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... genqamdemod.cc: In function ‘octave_value_list Fgenqamdemod(const octave_value_list&, int)’: genqamdemod.cc:39:57: warning: ‘int empty_arg(const char*, octave_idx_type, octave_idx_type)’ is deprecated: use 'octave_value::is_empty' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]    int arg_is_empty1 = empty_arg ("genqamdemod", nr1, nc1);
                                                         ^ In file included from /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/oct.h:40:0,
                 from genqamdemod.cc:17: /usr/include/octave-4.2.2/octave/../octave/utils.h:58:26: note: declared here  extern OCTINTERP_API int empty_arg (const char *name, octave_idx_type nr,
                          ^~~~~~~~~ make: Entering directory '/tmp/oct-OcFw19/communications-1.2.1/src' /usr/bin/mkoctfile
-DGALOIS_DISP_PRIVATES -DHAVE_OCTAVE_HDF5_ID_TYPE=1 __errcore__.cc -o __errcore__.oct /usr/bin/mkoctfile -DGALOIS_DISP_PRIVATES -DHAVE_OCTAVE_HDF5_ID_TYPE=1 __gfweight__.cc -o __gfweight__.oct /usr/bin/mkoctfile -DGALOIS_DISP_PRIVATES -DHAVE_OCTAVE_HDF5_ID_TYPE=1 cyclgen.cc -o cyclgen.oct /usr/bin/mkoctfile -DGALOIS_DISP_PRIVATES
-DHAVE_OCTAVE_HDF5_ID_TYPE=1 cyclpoly.cc -o cyclpoly.oct /usr/bin/mkoctfile -DGALOIS_DISP_PRIVATES -DHAVE_OCTAVE_HDF5_ID_TYPE=1 genqamdemod.cc -o genqamdemod.oct /usr/bin/mkoctfile
-DGALOIS_DISP_PRIVATES -DHAVE_OCTAVE_HDF5_ID_TYPE=1 -c galois-def.cc -o galois-def.o Makefile:45: recipe for target 'galois-def.o' failed make: Leaving directory '/tmp/oct-OcFw19/communications-1.2.1/src'

pkg: error running `make' for the communications package. error: called from
    configure_make at line 95 column 9
    install at line 194 column 7
    pkg at line 394 column 9
```

can anyone help with this  ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try to install the `communications package` from ubuntu's terminal with the following command.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave-communications
```

And check it:

```
>> pkg list
Package Name    | Version | Installation directory
----------------+---------+-----------------------
communications *|   1.2.1 | /usr/share/octave/packages/communications-1.2.1
       control *|   3.2.0 | /home/hugo/octave/control-3.2.0
        signal  |   1.4.1 | /home/hugo/octave/signal-1.4.1
```

Then try to use it and it works:
`>> pkg load communications`

Comment: Thanks, this saved my day, it looks like the package in the repo https://octave.sourceforge.io/communications/index.html is not compatible with the octave version from ubuntu's repos and can't compile, this works quite well though!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some refactoring has taken place and the communications package needs to be updated. In theory it seems like a simple fix. You could contact Mike Miller (the maintainer, as specified in the package's page: https://octave.sourceforge.io/communications/index.html ) and let them know, or you could attempt to rename the mentioned functions yourself.